# Quelle est la difference entre les mots « puisque » et « comme » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, conjonctions

Dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces mots ?

Y a-t-il une différence d'utilisation ou de sens ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ajoutons *parce que* et *car*.

- *parce que* et *comme* introduisent une cause.  La proposition introduite par *comme* précède généralement sa conséquence, celle introduite par *parce que* la suit. (À noter que *comme* a d'autres usages dans les quelles la proposition introduite par *comme* suit une autre).
- *car* introduit une justification ou une explication
- *puisque* introduit soit une cause, soit une justification, mais avec l'idée qu'elle est déjà connue de l'interlocuteur.

La nuance entre une cause et une justification est parfois faible.  Un exemple pour la clarifier :

> Je suis venu parce que ma femme restait à la maison.

Sous-entends presque une dispute.  C'est le fait que ma femme reste à la maison qui fait que je suis venu.

> Je suis venu car ma femme restait à la maison.

Ouvre le champs à d'autres possibilités. Par exemple il était prévu que je reste à la maison pour attendre un artisan devant faire des travaux et j'avais prévenu de mon absence, ma femme étant là, ça me laisse la possibilité de venir.

Comment: Très bonne réponse, mais les exemples ne sont pas completement limpides.

Comment: Si tu as mieux, je suis preneur.

Comment: *Parce que* et *comme* expriment une cause **inconnue de l'interlocuteur**.  *Puisque*  exprime une cause connue de l'interlocuteur - mais ça tu l'as bien dit.