# Quel est la différence entre « puisque » et « comme » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens

Je suis étudiante de français. La professeur explique « connu et non » mais je ne comprends pas. SVP, expliquez-moi.

Comment: Je viens de voir que la question a déjà été posée ici sur French Language : [Quelle est la difference entre les mots « puisque » et « comme » ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6423/358) et il y a la réponse. Ta question sera probablement fermée mais n'hésite pas à revenir avec d'autres questions.

Comment: Nothing. Ok, Thank , I am looking that question u mentioned.